# String matching Python

Tags: python, loops, parsing, match

Hi guys i have this code tha compares two files and finds matches.

```
import csv
import re

with open('ip-new.txt','r') as csvfile1, open('city.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8" ) as file1:
    readCS = csv.reader(csvfile1, delimiter=';')
    reader = file1.readlines()
    for row in readCS:
        for line in reader:
            if row[0] in line.upper() and row[1] in line.upper():
                print(str(row[::1]) + line)
```

So far so good. the output is the following.

```
['IT', 'OLBIA'] 'id': 'IT~25~Solbiate'

['IT', 'OLBIA'] 'id': 'IT~25~Solbiate Arno'

['IT', 'OLBIA'] 'id': 'IT~25~Solbiate Olona'

['IT', 'OLBIA'] 'id': 'IT~88~Olbia'
```

You will see my problem is it finds 3 additional matches. Is there a way i can limit just to the last match ?

iam looking to output this match :

```
['IT', 'OLBIA'] 'id': 'IT~88~Olbia'
```

Comment: Seems to me, that you should restrict the match to a preceding `~`, for which you would need a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wanting to do a whole-word case-insensitive search.

You will want the regular expression package:

```
import re
```

and then after that you can replace:

```
            if row[0] in line.upper() and row[1] in line.upper():
```

with:

```
            if (re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(row[0]), line, re.IGNORECASE) and
                re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(row[1]), line, re.IGNORECASE)):
```

or you could write this as:

```
            if all(re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(word), line, re.IGNORECASE)
                   for word in row[:2]):
```

(If `row` *only* contains two columns, you could use `row` in place of `row[:2]`.)

Here, the `\b` means to match a word boundary (and the `r` before the string means to treat it as a raw string, rather than interpret the `\` as starting an escape sequence).

And in Python >= 3.6, this could be written more concisely as:

```
            if all(re.search(fr"\b{word}\b", line, re.IGNORECASE) for word in row[:2]):
```

Here, adding the `f` before the `r` means that although the string is a raw string as regards the `\`, any `{var}` will be substituted with the value. This makes it clearer that the pattern consists of `word` with word boundaries (`\b`) before and after it.

Answer (score 0):

If your data in `city.txt` is consistent and follows the convention of `'id': 'XX~YY~Zzzz'`, you can try to parse the data and split the string, based on the character `~`.

So for example:

```
city1 = "'id': 'IT~25~Solbiate'"
city2 = "'id': 'IT~88~Olbia'"

# remove the quotes and extract the city id
_, city1_id = city1.replace("'", "").split(':')
_, city2_id = city2.replace("'", "").split(':')

# remove the space at the beginning
city1_id = city1_id.strip()
city2_id = city2_id.strip()

# use split('~') to have an exact match
print("Olbia in {0}? {1}".format(city1, 'OLBIA' in city1_id.upper().split('~')))
print("Olbia in {0}? {1}".format(city2, 'OLBIA' in city2_id.upper().split('~')))
```